# 303 error when submitting form from modal in codeigniter4 when csrf is enabled

Tags: php, modal-dialog, csrf, codeigniter-4

I have a codeignter4 web application with the following view which has a modal which submits data.

```
<script>
    function deleteConfirm(url){
        $('#btn-delete').attr('href', url);
        $('#deleteModal').modal();
    }
</script>

<!-- Begin Page Content -->
<div class="container-fluid">

    <!-- Page Heading -->
    <h1 class="h3 mb-4 text-gray-800"><?= esc($title); ?></h1>
    <div class="col-lg-7">
        
        <?php if(session()->getFlashdata('message')):?>
         <?= session()->getFlashdata('message') ?>
                                  
          <?php endif;
             unset($_SESSION['message']);
            ?>
    </div>

    <div class="card col-lg-7 shadow mb-4">
        <div class="card-header py-3">
            <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary"><a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newRoleModal"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add New</a></h6>
        </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                    <!--<thead class="thead-dark">-->
<thead class="bg-warning">
                                <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th>Authority</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                        </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php $index = 1; ?>
                        <?php foreach($role as $r) : ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?= esc($index); ?></td>
                                <td><?= esc($r['role']); ?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="badge badge-primary" style="font-size:14px;" href="<?= site_url('admin/roleaccess/'.$r['id']); ?>">Manage Access</a>
                                    <a class="badge badge-success" style="font-size:14px;" href="<?= site_url('admin/editrole/'.$r['id']); ?>">Update</a>
                                    <a class="badge badge-danger" style="font-size:14px;" href="#!" onclick="deleteConfirm('<?= site_url('admin/deleterole/'.$r['id']); ?>')">Delete</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php $index++; ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- /.container-fluid -->

</div>
<!-- End of Main Content -->

<!-- Modal add new role-->
<div class="modal fade" id="newRoleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="newRoleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="newRoleModalLabel">Add New Authority</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <!-- form -->
      <?php

          $attributes = array('id' => 'myform'); ?>
                                
    <?= form_open('admin/addrole'); ?>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="role" name="role" placeholder="Name of Authority">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
        </div>
      <? = form_close(); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- modal delete -->
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Are you sure?</h5>
        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">Deleted data cannot be recovered!!</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <a id="btn-delete" class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Remove</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The form submit redirects to the view itself when csrf is enabled. When I check the web console Network tab it shows a 303 status on addrole which is the controller method that handles the form submit data. However it works fine when csrf is disabled.How can I get it working

My Filter Class

```
<?php

namespace Config;

use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\CSRF;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\DebugToolbar;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\Honeypot;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\InvalidChars;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\SecureHeaders;

class Filters extends BaseConfig
{
    /**
     * Configures aliases for Filter classes to
     * make reading things nicer and simpler.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $aliases = [
        'csrf'          => CSRF::class,
        'toolbar'       => DebugToolbar::class,
        'honeypot'      => Honeypot::class,
        'invalidchars'  => InvalidChars::class,
        'secureheaders' => SecureHeaders::class,
        'auth'     => \App\Filters\Auth::class,
    ];

    /**
     * List of filter aliases that are always
     * applied before and after every request.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    /*public $globals = [
        'before' => [
            // 'honeypot',
             'csrf',
            // 'invalidchars',
        ],
        'after' => [
            //'toolbar',
            // 'honeypot',
            // 'secureheaders',
        ],
    ];*/
    public $globals = [
'before' => [
 //'honeypot',
 'csrf',
//'isLoggedIn' => ['except' => ['/', 'admin','users', 'dashboard', 'logout','auth','Ticket/getStatusCounts']],
//'isGranted' => ['except' => ['/', 'admin', 'users','dashboard', 'logout','auth', 'blocked', 'home', 'Welcome/*','Registration/*','profile','profile_save','profile_edit','Ticket/getStatusCounts']],
],
'after' => [
'toolbar',
// 'honeypot',
],
];

    /**
     * List of filter aliases that works on a
     * particular HTTP method (GET, POST, etc.).
     *
     * Example:
     * 'post' => ['foo', 'bar']
     *
     * If you use this, you should disable auto-routing because auto-routing
     * permits any HTTP method to access a controller. Accessing the controller
     * with a method you don’t expect could bypass the filter.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $methods = [];

    /**
     * List of filter aliases that should run on any
     * before or after URI patterns.
     *
     * Example:
     * 'isLoggedIn' => ['before' => ['account/*', 'profiles/*']]
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $filters = [];
}
```

My config/App file

```
<?php

namespace Config;

use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig;
use CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers\FileHandler;

class App extends BaseConfig
{
    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Base Site URL
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
     * WITH a trailing slash:
     *
     *    http://example.com/
     *
     * If this is not set then CodeIgniter will try guess the protocol, domain
     * and path to your installation. However, you should always configure this
     * explicitly and never rely on auto-guessing, especially in production
     * environments.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $baseURL = 'http://localhost/demo/public';

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Index File
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
     * something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
     * variable so that it is blank.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $indexPage = 'index.php';

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * URI PROTOCOL
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * This item determines which getServer global should be used to retrieve the
     * URI string.  The default setting of 'REQUEST_URI' works for most servers.
     * If your links do not seem to work, try one of the other delicious flavors:
     *
     * 'REQUEST_URI'    Uses $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
     * 'QUERY_STRING'   Uses $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
     * 'PATH_INFO'      Uses $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']
     *
     * WARNING: If you set this to 'PATH_INFO', URIs will always be URL-decoded!
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $uriProtocol = 'REQUEST_URI';

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Default Locale
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * The Locale roughly represents the language and location that your visitor
     * is viewing the site from. It affects the language strings and other
     * strings (like currency markers, numbers, etc), that your program
     * should run under for this request.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $defaultLocale = 'en';

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Negotiate Locale
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * If true, the current Request object will automatically determine the
     * language to use based on the value of the Accept-Language header.
     *
     * If false, no automatic detection will be performed.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $negotiateLocale = false;

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Supported Locales
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * If $negotiateLocale is true, this array lists the locales supported
     * by the application in descending order of priority. If no match is
     * found, the first locale will be used.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    public $supportedLocales = ['en'];

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Application Timezone
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * The default timezone that will be used in your application to display
     * dates with the date helper, and can be retrieved through app_timezone()
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $appTimezone = 'Asia/Kolkata';

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Default Character Set
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * This determines which character set is used by default in various methods
     * that require a character set to be provided.
     *
     * @see http://php.net/htmlspecialchars for a list of supported charsets.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $charset = 'UTF-8';

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * URI PROTOCOL
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * If true, this will force every request made to this application to be
     * made via a secure connection (HTTPS). If the incoming request is not
     * secure, the user will be redirected to a secure version of the page
     * and the HTTP Strict Transport Security header will be set.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $forceGlobalSecureRequests = false;

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Session Driver
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * The session storage driver to use:
     * - `CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers\FileHandler`
     * - `CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers\DatabaseHandler`
     * - `CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers\MemcachedHandler`
     * - `CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers\RedisHandler`
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $sessionDriver = FileHandler::class;

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Session Cookie Name
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * The session cookie name, must contain only [0-9a-z_-] characters
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $sessionCookieName = 'ci_session';

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Session Expiration
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * The number of SECONDS you want the session to last.
     * Setting to 0 (zero) means expire when the browser is closed.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $sessionExpiration = 7200;

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Session Save Path
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * The location to save sessions to and is driver dependent.
     *
     * For the 'files' driver, it's a path to a writable directory.
     * WARNING: Only absolute paths are supported!
     *
     * For the 'database' driver, it's a table name.
     * Please read up the manual for the format with other session drivers.
     *
     * IMPORTANT: You are REQUIRED to set a valid save path!
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $sessionSavePath = WRITEPATH . 'session';

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Session Match IP
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * Whether to match the user's IP address when reading the session data.
     *
     * WARNING: If you're using the database driver, don't forget to update
     *          your session table's PRIMARY KEY when changing this setting.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $sessionMatchIP = false;

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Session Time to Update
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * How many seconds between CI regenerating the session ID.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $sessionTimeToUpdate = 300;

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Session Regenerate Destroy
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * Whether to destroy session data associated with the old session ID
     * when auto-regenerating the session ID. When set to FALSE, the data
     * will be later deleted by the garbage collector.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $sessionRegenerateDestroy = false;

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Cookie Prefix
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * Set a cookie name prefix if you need to avoid collisions.
     *
     * @var string
     *
     * @deprecated use Config\Cookie::$prefix property instead.
     */
    public $cookiePrefix = '';

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Cookie Domain
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * Set to `.your-domain.com` for site-wide cookies.
     *
     * @var string
     *
     * @deprecated use Config\Cookie::$domain property instead.
     */
    public $cookieDomain = '';

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Cookie Path
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * Typically will be a forward slash.
     *
     * @var string
     *
     * @deprecated use Config\Cookie::$path property instead.
     */
    public $cookiePath = '/';

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Cookie Secure
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * Cookie will only be set if a secure HTTPS connection exists.
     *
     * @var bool
     *
     * @deprecated use Config\Cookie::$secure property instead.
     */
    public $cookieSecure = false;

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Cookie HttpOnly
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * Cookie will only be accessible via HTTP(S) (no JavaScript).
     *
     * @var bool
     *
     * @deprecated use Config\Cookie::$httponly property instead.
     */
    public $cookieHTTPOnly = true;

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Cookie SameSite
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * Configure cookie SameSite setting. Allowed values are:
     * - None
     * - Lax
     * - Strict
     * - ''
     *
     * Alternatively, you can use the constant names:
     * - `Cookie::SAMESITE_NONE`
     * - `Cookie::SAMESITE_LAX`
     * - `Cookie::SAMESITE_STRICT`
     *
     * Defaults to `Lax` for compatibility with modern browsers. Setting `''`
     * (empty string) means default SameSite attribute set by browsers (`Lax`)
     * will be set on cookies. If set to `None`, `$cookieSecure` must also be set.
     *
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @deprecated use Config\Cookie::$samesite property instead.
     */
    public $cookieSameSite = 'Lax';

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Reverse Proxy IPs
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * If your server is behind a reverse proxy, you must whitelist the proxy
     * IP addresses from which CodeIgniter should trust headers such as
     * HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR and HTTP_CLIENT_IP in order to properly identify
     * the visitor's IP address.
     *
     * You can use both an array or a comma-separated list of proxy addresses,
     * as well as specifying whole subnets. Here are a few examples:
     *
     * Comma-separated: '10.0.1.200,192.168.5.0/24'
     * Array: ['10.0.1.200', '192.168.5.0/24']
     *
     * @var string|string[]
     */
    public $proxyIPs = '';

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * CSRF Token Name
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * The token name.
     *
     * @deprecated Use `Config\Security` $tokenName property instead of using this property.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $CSRFTokenName = 'csrf_test_name';

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * CSRF Header Name
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * The header name.
     *
     * @deprecated Use `Config\Security` $headerName property instead of using this property.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $CSRFHeaderName = 'X-CSRF-TOKEN';

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * CSRF Cookie Name
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * The cookie name.
     *
     * @deprecated Use `Config\Security` $cookieName property instead of using this property.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $CSRFCookieName = 'csrf_cookie_name';

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * CSRF Expire
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * The number in seconds the token should expire.
     *
     * @deprecated Use `Config\Security` $expire property instead of using this property.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $CSRFExpire = 7200;

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * CSRF Regenerate
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * Regenerate token on every submission?
     *
     * @deprecated Use `Config\Security` $regenerate property instead of using this property.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $CSRFRegenerate = false;

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * CSRF Redirect
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * Redirect to previous page with error on failure?
     *
     * @deprecated Use `Config\Security` $redirect property instead of using this property.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $CSRFRedirect = false;

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * CSRF SameSite
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * Setting for CSRF SameSite cookie token. Allowed values are:
     * - None
     * - Lax
     * - Strict
     * - ''
     *
     * Defaults to `Lax` as recommended in this link:
     *
     * @see https://portswigger.net/web-security/csrf/samesite-cookies
     * @deprecated `Config\Cookie` $samesite property is used.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $CSRFSameSite = 'Lax';

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Content Security Policy
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * Enables the Response's Content Secure Policy to restrict the sources that
     * can be used for images, scripts, CSS files, audio, video, etc. If enabled,
     * the Response object will populate default values for the policy from the
     * `ContentSecurityPolicy.php` file. Controllers can always add to those
     * restrictions at run time.
     *
     * For a better understanding of CSP, see these documents:
     *
     * @see http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/
     * @see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $CSPEnabled = false;
    
   

}
```

My Security class

```
<?php

namespace Config;

use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig;

class Security extends BaseConfig
{
    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * CSRF Protection Method
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * Protection Method for Cross Site Request Forgery protection.
     *
     * @var string 'cookie' or 'session'
     */
    public $csrfProtection = 'cookie';

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * CSRF Token Randomization
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * Randomize the CSRF Token for added security.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $tokenRandomize = true;

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * CSRF Token Name
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * Token name for Cross Site Request Forgery protection.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $tokenName = 'csrf_test_name';

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * CSRF Header Name
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * Header name for Cross Site Request Forgery protection.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $headerName = 'X-CSRF-TOKEN';

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * CSRF Cookie Name
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * Cookie name for Cross Site Request Forgery protection.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $cookieName = 'csrf_cookie_name';

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * CSRF Expires
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * Expiration time for Cross Site Request Forgery protection cookie.
     *
     * Defaults to two hours (in seconds).
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $expires = 7200;

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * CSRF Regenerate
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * Regenerate CSRF Token on every submission.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $regenerate = false;

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * CSRF Redirect
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * Redirect to previous page with error on failure.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $redirect = true;

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * CSRF SameSite
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * Setting for CSRF SameSite cookie token.
     *
     * Allowed values are: None - Lax - Strict - ''.
     *
     * Defaults to `Lax` as recommended in this link:
     *
     * @see https://portswigger.net/web-security/csrf/samesite-cookies
     *
     * @var string
     *
     * @deprecated `Config\Cookie` $samesite property is used.
     */
    public $samesite = 'Lax';
}
```

Please help me to get the form submission working when csrf is enabled.

MY Codeigniter4 application with a view having a modal which submits form data. This sends a 303 http status when csrf is enalbed; however the form submits data correctly when csrf is disabled.
Where should I correct to get it working with csrf enabled.

Comment: 303 is a redirect, not an error.

Comment: how can i get rid of 303 redirect

Comment: Double check in your HTML whether CI has added the csrf_ fields in your form. If not, that might help work out the problem.

Comment: CI has added the csrf fields in the form automatically

Comment: I had a duplicate csrf field added manually in the footer loaded separately. When I removed it , the problem got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add csrf_token and hash in ajax param or include csrf_field in form.

```
For Ajax

var token = '<?= csrf_token(); ?>';
var hash = '<?= csrf_hash(); ?>';

ajaxParam = {
... ,
[token] : hash
};

$.ajax({....});

For Form submit

add in form html

<?= csrf_field(); ?>
```